# What is the semantics and functionality of file scope return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, return

It's all in the title.
One part of my coding style is adding `return` whenever a function with a callback parameter is called, e.g.:

```
(function() {
    return whatever(function() /* callback */ { // Note the "return" keyword here
        // ...
    });
})();
```

For quite a while, I have been using the same construct for file scope function calls with a callback parameter, but I wonder if this can cause side-effects I am not aware of.

I could not find any documentation on the subject, and was unable to find out what it does.

Thanks!

[**tl;dr**] What does using the `return` keyword mean at file scope and what does it do?